# images appear in development, but not in production in "REACT"

Tags: reactjs, image, import

this is my first question.
I am doing my first real site in react. (After several months of learning without "yarn build" ....)
The answer is certainly obvious but I can't find any answer on the internet.

in development I import my images in this way:

```
import greg from 'src/assets/image/Grincheux.png';
```

Then I use it this way :

```
<img className="photo_greg" alt="" src={greg} />
```

so far it's good, with "yarn start" I can see my images appear.
But when I put online, after having "yarn build", the images are no longer there.

I understand that the image paths have been modified, however I don't understand that the "build" does not modify the paths from the component.

I tried to put the path directly from "DIST", but I understood that it is useless .... 
can you tell me what i missed?

(there is a lot of information on internet creation but online and these traps ... )

thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found my problem it was a one page route so when I did "yarn build" the path to the images for that page only didn't work. I don't know exactly why, but in any case the error came from here. I hope it can help someone like me.

```
WRONG : <li><NavLink to="***advice-sheet/***about" title="Notre vision">Notre vision</NavLink></li>



Right : <li><NavLink to="/about" title="Notre vision">Notre vision</NavLink></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you can try using relative paths instead of absolute paths.

```
 // Instead of absloute path
import greg from 'src/assets/image/Grincheux.png';

// Use relative path depending on your folder structure. "../../" is for example,
// you should replace according to your folder structure
import greg from '../../image/Grincheux.png';
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. but it doesn't work either 